# onClick does not workon first click

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, dom-events

I'm trying to let a `button` element switch its text between 'Follow' and 'Unfollow', but why isn't the Javascript reacting on the first click on the button?

**HTML:**

```
<form method="post">
    <button class="follow" onclick="this.innerHTML = follow_test(this.innerHTML)">

        Follow

    </button>
</form>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
    function follow_test(string) {
        if (string === 'Follow') { return ('Unfollow'); } else { return('Follow'); }
    }
```

Comment: It probably has whitespace.

Comment: `display: contents` doesn't do anything.

Comment: @SLaks - "probably"? You can see it right here on the page, the line-breaks alone are enough to ruin the scheme as presented.

Comment: Try `string.trim() === 'Follow'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Slaks pointed out, the reason was because of the white-space in your button text which caused the else statement to run instead since `"    string    "` is not *strictly equal* ( === ) to `"string"`.

You can just use the **[innerText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText)** property which ignores white-space instead of the **innerHTML** property like this:

```js
/* JavaScript */
var btn = document.querySelector("button");

function follow_test(string) { 
    let text = string.target;

    if (text.innerText === "Follow") {
        text.innerText = "Unfollow";
    } else {
        text.innerText = "Follow";
    }    
}

btn.addEventListener("click", follow_test);
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<form method="post">
    <button type="button" class="follow"> // added 'type="button"' to prevent page reload for example's sake
        Follow
    </button>
</form>
```

---

Or if you prefer sticking with the **[innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)** property or want to use the **[textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)** property instead, you can just use the [trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) method on the button string to remove all white-space before and after the string like this:

```js
/* JavaScript */
var btn = document.querySelector("button");

function follow_test(string) { 
    let text = string.target;
    
    if ((text.innerHTML).trim() === "Follow") {
        text.innerHTML = "Unfollow"; 
    } else {
        text.innerHTML = "Follow";
    }
    
}

btn.addEventListener("click", follow_test);
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<form method="post">
    <button type="button" class="follow"> // added 'type="button"' to prevent page reload for example's sake
        Follow
    </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues here;

First, the default "submit" behaivor of the `<button>` element will be taking affect during user click, which in the case of the `<button>` will cause the browser to reload and refresh the page. As a result, the expected behaivor won't be observed due to the page reload.

To prevent the page reload behavior you can simply `return false;` in the event handler:

```
<button onclick="return false;">
Return false stops page reload on button click
</button>
```

The second issue is that the input `string` passed to `follow_test()` needs to be santized (ie removing whitespaces) to ensure that that `string === 'Follow'` evaluates true so that `Unfollow` is shown immediatly after the first click. This can be achieved via the `trim()` method:

```js
function follow_test(string) {
  if (string.trim() === 'Follow') {
    return ('Unfollow');
  } else {
    return ('Follow');
  }
}
```

```html
<form method="post">
  <button class="follow" onclick="this.innerHTML = follow_test(this.innerHTML); return false;">

        Follow

    </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.onclick`. In a way, it's easier to understand :

```js
var button = document.getElementsByClassName("follow")[0];

button.onclick = function(e) { 
  if(button.textContent == "Follow") { button.innerText = "Unfollow" } 
  else { button.innerText = "Follow" }

}
```

```html
<button class="follow">Follow</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is whitespace, try

#### Javascript

```
function follow_test(string) {
   if (string.indexOf('Follow')!== -1) { 
      return ('Unfollow'); 
   } else { 
      return('Follow');
   }
}
```

or you could change your HTML to the following and use innerText which will remove the white space and make your current function work:

#### HTML

```
<form method="post">
   <button class="follow" onclick="this.innerText = follow_test(this.innerText)">
   Follow
   </button>
</form>
```

#### OR

It might be better to use a class (or function with closure) to check the state of the button in order to toggle as checking the state or the HTML is dangerous, anything else in the code could ultimately alter it and break the functionality

Something like this:

#### Javascript

```
class toggleFollowState {
   toggle(){
      this.state = !this.state
      return this.getState()
   }
   getState(){
      return this.state ? 'Unfollow' : 'Follow'
   }
}

const followState = new toggleFollowState()
console.log(followState.toggle())
// logs true
console.log(followState.toggle())
// logs false
console.log(followState.getState())
// logs false
```

now you can set the HTML up like this

#### HTML

```
<form method="post">
   <button class="follow" onclick="this.innerHTML = followState.toggle()">
   Follow
   </button>
</form>
```

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this below code.

```
<form method="post">
    <button class="follow" type="button" onclick="if(this.innerHTML == 'unFollow'){ this.innerHTML='Follow';}else{this.innerHTML='unFollow';};return false">
        Follow
    </button>
</form>
```

Comment: <form method="post">
    <button class="follow" type="button" onclick="if(this.innerHTML == 'unFollow'){ this.innerHTML='Follow';}else{this.innerHTML='unFollow';};return false">
        Follow
    </button>
</form>

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>

        <button id="toggle" onclick="myFunction()">Follow</button>

        <script>

            function myFunction() {
                var change = document.getElementById("toggle");
                if (change.innerHTML == "Follow")
                {
                    change.innerHTML = "Unfollow";
                }
                else {
                    change.innerHTML = "Follow";
                }
            }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why you don't like this ? is it for being inline javascript ?